# C++ Virtual keyword and System update

Tags: c++

If I have legacy c++ code as follows:

```
class A 
{
    virtual void Method1() {  cout << "A::Method1()" << std::endl; }
}
int main()
{

    A *a = new A;

    a->Method1();
}
```

And I want to add or update with the following new code:

```
class B : A
{
    void Method1() { cout << "B:Method1()" << std::endl; }
}
```

How is the system updated so that method1() in the derived class gets called instead of the method1() in the base class, with the line a->Method1() ?  I understand that the virtual function table will be updated to call method1() in the derived class, but main() would also have to be updated as follows:

```
int main()
{
​    A *a = new B;
​
​    a->Method1();
​}
```

Output:

B:Method1()

Otherwise A:Method1() will continue to get called. I have verified this under visual studio.

Anyway point of fact is - Having to update main() defeats the purpose of defining Method1() as virtual, because you would have to change main(), then recompile it all, install, and deploy it.

Comment: That's how virtual functions, inheritance and polymorphism work in C++. The expression `new A` will create only an `A` object, it will have no knowledge of any child-classes.

Comment: You are right, having method `Method1` virtual in this code is completely pointless. There is no polymorphism because there is only one class implementing interface of class A and there is no separation of binary code since you create class B inplace. In order to make it a bit useful you need to decouple user code utilizing interface (that is `main` body) and library code (supplying concrete implementation of interface. Make a dll with function a like `unique_ptr<A> spawn()` and call it from `main`. This way you will be able to alter class implementing interface A without modifying `main`.

Comment: Well, you only have to recompile `main()` becuase that is where the `new` statement was. If the `new` was somewhere else, like in a factory class or hidden behind a pimpl then you would only recompile all parts.

Comment: You have to recompile the software regardless because that new code for `class B` is not going to compile itself.

Comment: UPDATED: Intuitively,  this should work by updating the virtual function table to point to the overridden function, then when legacy or new code is run, it should execute the new function by going through the table. Obviously, you would have to compile the object for the new class, and link it with all legacy objects, and any updates to the virtual function table are done. You shouldn’t have to modify legacy code. But I know it does not work this way.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you've said above is correct. You seem to misunderstand the purpose of virtual methods. The purpose is not to save you having to recompile and reinstall you application when you improve a method. In fact, you don't use inheritance just to improve a method. You use inheritance to show that different classes are related in some way. Virtual functions allow some inherited classes to share functionality and others to supply their own.

In other words, you don't make a `class B` to improve on `class A`. You make a `class B` because you have other work to be done that is in some way related to the work done by `class A`.

Note that you could use an interface-style (or mix-in) base class as the parent class of a plug-in. Then you would only have to recompile your plug-in and have your app reload it. Usually the base class would have several pure virtual methods that the plug-in subclasses would implement.